# How can I detect a visitor's browser using PHP?

Tags: php

Followed the steps presented on [Beginner PHP Tutorial - How To Detect a Visitors Browser](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?video=17054)
 and got different result.

### ***Run the following code:***

```
<?php
  $browser = get_browser(null, true);
  echo $browser['browser'];
?>
```

### ***Result on Google Chrome:***

[image: Result on Google Chrome] 
Instead of displaying *Chrome*, the browser displayed *Default Browser*.

### **Files in my folder:**

- *browscap.ini*  - C:\xampp\php\extras
- *php.ini* - clearly specified the path of browscap.ini as shown below;

[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

What should I do to get the correct type of browser to be displayed on the page?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php see the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. That's not going to say `Chrome` either but I think it will be better than `default browser`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to detect your browser :

```
function getBrowser(){

$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$name = 'NA';


if (preg_match('/MSIE/i', $agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Internet Explorer';
} elseif (preg_match('/Firefox/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Mozilla Firefox';
} elseif (preg_match('/Chrome/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Google Chrome';
} elseif (preg_match('/Safari/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Apple Safari';
} elseif (preg_match('/Opera/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Opera';
} elseif (preg_match('/Netscape/i', $agent)) {
    $name = 'Netscape';
}


return $name;
```

}

```
echo getBrowser();
```

Comment: This is wrong nowadayas. Now `preg_match('/Chrome/i', $agent)` will return Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser();
print_r($browser);
```